# Show that the auto covariance of X_k does not depend on µ

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, autoregressive

Let define the time series {X_k}*(k in Z)
X_k=µ+(Z_k)+ßZ*(k-1)

µ and ß are constant and Z_k is a white noise process. show that the a.c.v.f of X_k does not depend on µ

Comment: Welcome to CV! Since you’re new here, you may want to take our tour, which has information for new users.  Since this looks like homework (apologies if it's not), please add the [self-study] tag and read its wiki. Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing. If this is self-study rather than homework, let us know, and... it's still a good idea to show us what you've tried.  Also, use Mathjax!